# Netbeans 7.4 issue: build-impl.xml is overwritten as build-impl.xml~ at shutdown

Tags: java, netbeans

Every time I shut down Netbeans 7.4, the build-impl.xml swaps name to build-impl.xml~, and so when I reopen Netbeans and run my project, I immediately get the error

*build.xml:12: Cannot find nbproject/build-impl.xml imported from build.xml*

Simply renaming the file build-impl.xml resolves the issue, but it is a pain to do each time. What is causing this issue, and is there a more permanent solution?

Thanks

Comment: OS? Any change you've the file opened with another editor (for instance Vim on Linux/Mac OS)?

Comment: I'm using OS Mavericks. I've not opened it with another editor recently (not in between opening and closing netbeans the last time). As soon as I close Netbeans, it changes the name of the file.

Comment: Open the folder with the terminal app after you have closed Netbeans and paste the output of ls -alh

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   8 samhincks  staff   272B Jan  7 10:12 . 

drwxr-xr-x  52 samhincks  staff   1.7K Jan  6 11:20 ..

-rw-r--r--   1 samhincks  staff   6.6K Aug 12 15:51 ant-deploy.xml

-rw-r--r--   1 samhincks  staff    78K Nov 14 16:49 build-impl.xml~
-rw-r--r--   1 samhincks  staff   465B Aug 13 17:43 genfiles.properties
drwxr-xr-x   4 samhincks  staff   136B Sep  2 14:25 private
-rw-r--r--   1 samhincks  staff   6.5K Jan  6 11:18 project.properties
-rw-r--r--   1 samhincks  staff   4.0K Dec 25 17:28 project.xml

Comment: Also, the name changing occurs upon re-opening and not closing, it appears.

Comment: what if you try to do 'grep -Ril "build-impl.xml~" *'. I guess the project files are corrupted.

Comment: "grep -Ril "build-impl.xml~" *" returns nothing.

Comment: I'm running out of options here. The not-so-smart-but-maybe-quick solution would be to create a new project and reimport the sources. Sorry I wasn't able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in any case. Thats likely what I'll end up doing :)